# Deploying django docker container to elastic beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a django rest framework app configured with nginx + gunicorn. I can run the containers locally using `docker-compose up -d --build` just fine, but I wish to deploy the docker image to AWS elastic beanstalk.

For debugging purposes, I am trying `eb local run`, butI seem to be getting this error:

```
latest: Pulling from <user>/<repo>
Digest: sha256:15cec14272aca0b787c4209e3196b2e61d50732f6f4616f2cf50baa28b82c65c
Status: Image is up to date for <user>/<repo>:latest
docker.io/<user>/<repo>:latest
Sending build context to Docker daemon  316.7MB
Step 1/2 : FROM <user>/<repo>:latest
 ---> eex74e02e4e5
Step 2/2 : EXPOSE 8000
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 094f132e13a7
Successfully built 094f132e13a7
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.
ERROR: CommandError - None
```

Here is my Dockerrun.aws.json:

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
    "Image": {
      "Name": "<user>/<repo>:latest",
      "Update": "true"
    },
    "Ports": [
      {
        "ContainerPort": "8000"
      }
    ]
}
```

And if I actually deploy to EB, I see the following error in the logs:

```
----------------------------------------
/var/log/web.stdout.log
----------------------------------------
Aug 15 22:26:00 ip-172-31-24-230 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
Aug 15 22:26:00 ip-172-31-24-230 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
Aug 15 22:26:00 ip-172-31-24-230 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Aug 15 22:26:00 ip-172-31-24-230 web: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application'
Aug 15 22:26:00 ip-172-31-24-230 web: [2020-08-15 22:26:00 +0000] [3815] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 3815)
Aug 15 22:26:00 ip-172-31-24-230 web: [2020-08-15 22:26:00 +0000] [3808] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
Aug 15 22:26:00 ip-172-31-24-230 web: [2020-08-15 22:26:00 +0000] [3808] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
Aug 15 22:26:00 ip-172-31-24-230 web: [2020-08-15 22:26:00 +0000] [3820] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
Aug 15 22:26:00 ip-172-31-24-230 web: [2020-08-15 22:26:00 +0000] [3820] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (3820)
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: What heppens when you actually deploy it to EB?

Comment: nginx runs into a prblem: 502 bad gateway. But it works fine locally if I just run the docker-compose up -d command

Comment: What EB platform are you using? Seems to be a python, not single docker?

Comment: platform/Python 3.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.1.0, Sorry I'm new to this aws dev thing, but what do you mean by "single docker"

Comment: So its not docker environment, but regular python.

Comment: I'm making an answer with more details now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use docker on EB, you have two options:

- a [single Docker](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.html) platform
- a [Multicontainer Docker](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecs.html) platform

Since you are using [Dockerrun.aws.json v1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker-configuration.html), you should use `Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.1.0` platform (single docker), not `Python 3.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.1.0`.

The list of supported, single-docker platforms is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html#platforms-supported.docker).

In console it would be:

[image]

Comment: is there a way to do this from the command line? Also, I'm confused on whether I should be running a single docker container or a multicontainer docker platform. I currently have 3 separate containers (django+nginx+postgresdb), but all together in an image.

Comment: @humptydumpty Yes, you can do it CLI, in the same way as you did the python environment. But have to choose docker env when prompted. If you use 3 containers, you need multidocker container env. But you also need to use [Dockerrun.aws.json v2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_v2config.html#create_deploy_docker_v2config_dockerrun), not v1 as you do now.

Comment: Nice! I'll try this out to see how it goes, thanks!

Comment: quick question: im using docker-compose to build 3 containers (api, nginx, postgres) and run it locally. Since I need a multi-docker container env, I need to also push these to dockerhub. How do I push the official nginx and postgres containers? Or do I not push those?

Comment: @humptydumpty You don't have to push them. You just define their images in the Dockerrun file. EB will just use them from docker hub.